# Lambda trigger dynamic specific path s3 upload

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to create a lambda function that will get triggered once a folder is uploaded to a S3 Bucket. But the lambda will perform an operation that will save files back on the same folder, how can I do so without having a self calling function?

I want to upload the following folder structure to the bucket:

Project_0001/input/inputs.csv

The outputs will create and be saved on:

Project_0001/output/outputs.csv

But, my project number will change, so I can't simply assign a static prefix. Is there a way of dynamically change the prefix, something like:

Project_*/input/

Comment: 1) You can use S3 object meta data (user defined) to add a key called "Seen", set it to "Seen": "True". If the metadata key is not present on an object, then it is not processed and you can continue the lambda invocation and set this Metadata during putting the object to S3, otherwise return.
2) You can use suffix instead of prefix, call your files `fileName_processed.csv` and `fileName_unprocessed.csv` add trigger only for `_unprocessed.csv`.
3) You can check the prefix dynamically when the lambda function runs, similar to #1 and make an early return if it's processed already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Shubham's comment I drafted my solution using the prefix and suffix.

For my case, I stated the prefix being 'Project_' and for the suffix I choose one specific file for the trigger, so my suffix is '/input/myFile.csv'.

So every time I upload the structure Project_/input/allmyfiles_with_myFile.csv it triggers the function and then I save my output in the same project folder, under the output folder, thus not triggering the function again.

I get project name with the following code

```
key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
project_id = key.split("/")[0]
```